# How to map the escape sequence of Gnu-screen to an arbitary key remapped with xmodmap?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, xmodmap

so i remapped some keys using xmodmap, specifically i remapped one key to the ±-sign. I want to have this key as my escape for GNU screen. I tried adding the following lines in my .screenrc:

```
escape ±

escape ±±
```

but it doesn't work.

from the GNU Screen manual:

> escape xy
>
> Set the command character to x and the character generating a literal command character (by triggering the "meta" command) to y (similar to the -e option). Each argument is either a single character, a two-character sequence of the form "^x" (meaning "C-x"), a backslash followed by an octal number (specifying the ASCII code of the character), or a backslash followed by a second character, such as "^" or "". The default is "^Aa".

i do not understand how the default mapping is ^a when the line in screenrc is ^Aa.

Can someone explain this please?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

So:

`^A`   means that the escape sequence  is control-a

`a`    means if i need to send `control-a` to my shell , i need to type `control-a`  following by `a`

You can test by following this example

```
screen -e "^Ap"    #  start screen with escape set to ^Ap

bash               # to be sure we are in bash

set -o emacs       # we switch to emacs mode

echo hello         # we have some in history
```

`control-p` or `arrow UP`

your cursor must be at the end of the previous command must be  `echo hello`

`control-a` follow by `p`

you cursor must be at the begin of the line ( you send `ctrl-a` to the shell )